# How can I guarantee that cleanup code always runs, however a PHP program terminates?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, signals

I have some cleanup code that needs to run in PHP even if errors/exceptions/something else cause the program to quit early.

I know about `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler`, my questions are

- are there any other handlers I need to intercept?
- to what extent can I rely on destructors?
- aside from abnormal events outside the PHP environment, are there any in-language halt events which I ***can't*** link my cleanup code to?

Comment: Fatal errors like hitting memory_limit or parse errors while including files are uncatchable and unrecoverable, no custom code can be run after them.

Comment: Put it in a cron job. It's the "take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. " method.

Comment: If I run a cron job to run the cleanup code, how do I know the code isn't still running? I'd have to write out some kind of status flag when the code exited abnormally. Oh, wait, that's the *same* problem.